# jQuery Add/Remove DIVs count, track and limit the number added/removed

Tags: jquery, html

I'm building a form that wants to capture a veteran's military deployment history. The form will default to one deployment. They can add up to 3. What I want to do is when you click "Add Deployment" the number associated with id="remaining" changes from 2 to 1. If you click the button the a second time the button becomes disabled and id="remaining" changes from 1 to 0. If you click the remove button the reverse happens so if you're at 0 remaining and you click remove, it changes to 1 remaining and the Add Deployment button is enabled.  See the code below working on this [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DivineChef/3chff/8/)  NOTE the id="counter" isn't being used it can be removed if unused.

HTML

```
<div>
Location deployed:
<input type="text" size="15" placeholder="Location deployed">&nbsp;Date deployed:
<input type="text" size="15" placeholder="Date deployed">&nbsp;Date returned:
<input type="text" size="15" placeholder="Date returned">
</div>
<div id="counter">
<button class="add" type="button">Add Deployment</button> 
<span id="remaining">2</span>
remaining
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
    $('.add').click(function() {
    $(this).before('<div>Location deployed: <input type="text" placeholder="Location  
    deployed" size="15" > Date deployed: <input type="text" placeholder="Date deployed" 
    size="15">
    Date returned: <input type="text" placeholder="Date returned" size="15" >&nbsp;<span
   class="remove"><button type="button"> Remove </button> </span></div>');
    });

    $(document).on('click','.remove',function() {
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    });
```

Comment: The button is generated through script it's not in the HTML. The reason it's not initially in the code is I don't want to give the user the option to delete the first DIV. See link to the fiddle, you're welcome to update it for me :)

Comment: Sorry, I noticed that shortly after so I deleted it from my answer.  Does my answer makes sense to you?

Comment: The important jquery methods to use are .attr() (to enable/disable the button) and .val() (to get the contents of the span).  You can also use .prop() to modify the enable/disable attribute, depending on which version of jquery you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what part you are stuck with, but this should do it:

http://jsfiddle.net/mmilleruva/9C6Lw/

```
var remaining = 2;

function UpdateRemaining(isAdd){
if(isAdd){
    remaining = remaining - 1;
}
else{
    remaining = remaining + 1;
}

$('#remaining').text(remaining);
if(remaining == 0){
    $('#btn').prop("disabled",true);
} else{
       $('#btn').prop("disabled",false);
 }
}

$('.add').click(function () {
  $(this).before('<div>Location deployed: <input type="text" placeholder="Location deployed" size="15" > Date deployed: <input type="text" placeholder="Date deployed" size="15" > Date returned: <input type="text" placeholder="Date returned" size="15" >&nbsp;<span class="remove"><button type="button"> Remove </button> </span></div>');

UpdateRemaining(true);
});

 $(document).on('click', '.remove', function () {
  $(this).parent('div').remove();
   UpdateRemaining(false);      
});
```

Comment: Awesome thanks for the help due to my limited jQuery abilities.

Answer (score 1):

Try check the value of the span and validate in both .click() like:

```
  $('.add').click(function () {
      var $remind = parseInt($('#remaining').text());
      if($remind != 0){
      $(this).before('<div>Location deployed: <input type="text" placeholder="Location deployed" size="15" > Date deployed: <input type="text" placeholder="Date deployed" size="15" > Date returned: <input type="text" placeholder="Date returned" size="15" >&nbsp;<span class="remove"><button type="button"> Remove </button> </span></div>');
          $remind = $remind - 1
          $('#remaining').text($remind);

      }
      else{
      console.log('All added');
          $('.add').prop('disabled', true);
      }
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.remove', function () {
      $(this).parent('div').remove();
      var $remind = parseInt($('#remaining').text());
      $remind = $remind + 1
      $('#remaining').text($remind);
      if$('.add').prop('disabled', false);

  });
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Z5yJT/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of the deployments, which it seems like you're doing in the span.  You can grab this by selecting `$("#remaining").val()` and then incrementing it and decrementing it based on the user clicks.

In your remove function, you increment the span, in your add function, you decrement said span.  In your add function you have an if conditional to see if the val of the #remaining span is 0, if so, you disable add button $('.add).attr('enabled', false) or something like that.  In your remove function, you do the same thing, except check to see if it has been incremented to 1, and then set enabled to true.