# jQuery Add/Remove DIVs, limit the number of add

Tags: jquery, limit, each, parent, children

I need to create 7 different blocks but I would like to write it using classes so that I don't have to create a lot of IDs. I've tried the `each()` or `children()`, but still don't get it.

I tried to follow [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23573269/jquery-add-remove-divs-count-track-and-limit-the-number-added-removed).

```js
var remaining = 8;

function UpdateRemaining(isAdd) {
  if (isAdd) {
    remaining = remaining - 1;
  } else {
    remaining = remaining + 1;
  }

  $('.remaining').text(remaining);
  if (remaining == 0) {
    $('.add').hide();
  } else {
    $('.add').show();
  }
}

$(document).on('click', '.add', function() {
  $(this).before('<div class="form-group col-md-3"><input type="file" class="form-control"> <span class="remove"><br /><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"> Remove </button> </span></div>');

  UpdateRemaining(true);
});

$(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
  $(this).parent('div').remove();
  UpdateRemaining(false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section">
  <h3>Type A</h3>
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="">Title</label>
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <button class="add"><span class="remaining">8</span></button>
  <hr />
</div>
<div class="section">
  <h3>Type B</h3>
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="">Title</label>
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <button class="add"><span class="remaining">8</span></button>
  <hr />
</div>
```

Comment: What's the issue? Your code appears to work fine

Comment: When I click the button of the type B section, it'll affect the type A section. Should I use different IDs to control the button?